# How to change the color of the short version of the acronym in the list of acronym

Tags: hyperref, color, acronyms

I use the `Acronym` package. In the printed list of acronym (usually put at the beginning of the document) there is the short version of the acronym (in `bold` font) and after the full name of the acronym (in normal font).

I want to change the color of the short version of each acronym to `blue` (for example) and keep the color of the full name of the acronym in black.

How to do it ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue} 

\title{My Thesis Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.2\baselineskip} 
\tableofcontents\par}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}
\section*{List of Acronyms}  
\begin{acronym} \renewcommand{\\}{}  
\acro{TTC}{Tunisian Tourism Company} % <---- Make TTC in blue for example
\acro{CBT}{Central Bank of Tunisia}
% etc
\end{acronym}
\newpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section{First Section}
Text about the \ac{TTC}, etc
\section{Second Section}
Text about the \ac{CBT}, etc
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer would not work for me. Instead, the following would do the desired job of coloring the acronym's shorthands in their listing:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\acsfont{\color{blue}#1}}}}
```

This command modifies the command `\aclabelfont` which is used to display the shorthands.

This example shows how to use the code above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\acsfont{\color{blue}#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\section{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ML}{Machine Learning}
  \acro{NN}{Neural Networks}
  \acro{SE}{Something Else}
\end{acronym}

\section{A Section with Acronyms}
This section uses the acronyms \ac{ML} and \ac{NN}. Notice how only the colors of the acronym shorthands in the list of acronyms changes. The acronyms' color in the text does not change.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but I need to change the output of `\acs`. I tried with `\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\color{blue}#1\color{black}}` (and some derivatives). This doesn't work as intended, but it gets blue *s* in `\acsp`. How can it be done properly?

Comment: Ok, so `\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}` works, but it changes the color of all links (equations, etc.), so what if one wants to change **only** the color of \acs{} ?

Answer (score 5):

With your current settings, the List of Acronyms is typeset using a `description` environment, so you can change `\descriptionlabel` for the `acronym` environment using, for example:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries\color{blue} #1}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue} 

\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries\color{blue} #1}}

\title{My Thesis Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.2\baselineskip} 
\tableofcontents\par}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}
\section*{List of Acronyms}  
\begin{acronym} \renewcommand{\\}{}  
\acro{TTC}{Tunisiano Tourism Company} % <---- Make TTC in blue for example
\acro{CBT}{Central Bank of Tunisia}
% etc
\end{acronym}
\newpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section{First Section}
Text about the \ac{TTC}, etc
\section{Second Section}
Text about the \ac{CBT}, etc
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you were using the optional argument for `acronym` with a value different than `1`, then one simply would have to change `\bflabel`

```
\def\bflabel#1{{\textbf{\textsf{\color{blue}#1}}\hfill}}
```